# RegEx match a number at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a number at the end of a string, using a regex. For example, the string might look like:

```
var foo = '101*99+123.12'; // would match 123.12
var bar = '101*99+-123';   // would match -123
var str = '101*99+-123.';  // would match -123.
```

This is what I've got so far, but it seem to match the entire string if there is no decimal point:

```
foo.match(/\-?\d+.?\d+?$/);
```

I take this to mean:

- `\-?`: optional "-" symbol
- `\d+`: 1 or more digits
- `.?`: optional decimal point
- `\d+?`: optional 1 or more digits after decimal point
- `$`: match at the end of the string

What am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for actually trying something, showing your work, and explaining. It could be better if there was an included jsFiddle, but beggars can't be choosers... :) One quick note - `.` in the middle of a regex means "any character" (basically), not "period"; I think you should escape it, to be `\.?`. That might not be the only problem, just something I noticed in your description of the regex

Comment: Wow... Look how the simplest question gets lots of upvotes when the OP puts in effort.  Cheers!

Comment: Will the string always look like `x*y+z`?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've never been great with regex, but figured I know some of the basics so I played around for a while. And yes, the string will always be an equation of some sort. I'm looking for a way to pull the last full number out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` matches any character. You need to escape it as `\.`

Try this:

```
/-?\d+\.?\d*$/
```

That is:

```
-?           // optional minus sign
\d+          // one or more digits
\.?          // optional .
\d*          // zero or more digits
```

As you can see at [MDN's regex page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), `+?` is a non-greedy match of 1 or more, not an optional match of 1 or more.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize I needed to escape the `.`. I assume the `+?` is referring to the last digits match?

Comment: @Vitim.us - (_in case you're not joking_) He did not steal your answer: He answered before you and has not edited his answer since. Based on the comments, it looks like he helped to fix your answer, so I hope you're just kidding.

Comment: @Phil, sorry, when I was talking about _+?_ I was trying to explain why I didn't include it in my regex (I used _*_), and why it didn't work in yours. But yes, you had used it for the right-most digits.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- *side note*: the dash doesn't need to be escaped; it's only special in character classes (e.g. `[a-z]`).
- the dot *is* special; it means "match any character". You'll want to escape it: `\.`
- `\d+?` actually means: match at least one digit, but if the regex goes on after that part of the pattern, try to match the remaining regex as early as possible ("[lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)" or "non-greedy matching"). In your case this `?` just does nothing. To make those digits truly optional, use `\d*`.
- Finally, you might want to make the decimal point and the subsequent digits optional as a group: `(\.\d+)?`

Executive summary: `/-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job `/-?\d+\.?\d*$/`

```
result = subject.match(/-?\d+\.?\d*$/mg);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That won't match the OP's third case with a trailing decimal point. Also (from their first example) they don't want to match the `+`.

Comment: What did you use to analyze the regular expression?

Comment: @MaxArt I use RegexBuddy it's windows only, but it works fine on Mac OS X under Wineskin.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is always `x*y+z` then you could do this alternatively without a regex like so.

```
var foo = '101*99+123.12'; // would match 123.12
var bar = '101*99+-123';   // would match -123
var str = '101*99+-123.';  // would match -123.

function getLastNumber(string) {
    return string.split("+")[1];
}

console.log(getLastNumber(foo));
console.log(getLastNumber(bar));
console.log(getLastNumber(str));
```

Output

```
123.12
-123
-123.
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/SnA2X/)